# Setters and getters are not working on test project

Tags: java, setter, getter

I have three classes. And I am trying to test getters and setters.
For some reason after I set a variable in another class, the variable value is not changed in the original. These are my three classes:

```
package test;

 public class first {
 second sec;
 third t;

public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println("First");
    new first();

}
public first(){
    sec=new second();
    t=new third();
    sec.update();
}

}
```

//Second Class

```
package test;

public class second {
private int x;
private int y;
public second (){
  this.x=100;
  this.y=100;
  System.out.println("Second");
}
public void update(){
    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
}
public void setX(int x){ this.x=x;};
public void setY(int y){ this.y=y;};
public int getX (){ return this.x;};
public int getY (){ return this.y;};
}
```

//Third Class

```
package test;

public class third {
 second sec;
public third(){
    sec=new second();
    sec.setX(200);
    sec.setY(200);
    System.out.println("Third");
}
}
```

This is what prints out:

```
First
Second
Second
Third
100
100
```

I set x and y in the third class to be 200. And I checked that the third constructor is the last to be called. Therefore setting the values. But the values of x and y are not changed.

Comment: Do you know the difference between classes and objects?

Comment: Classes normally starts with upper case. For example: `public class Second {}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sec.update();` call prints the values of X and Y of a different instance of `second` class than the one for which you updated their values.

```
public first(){
    sec=new second(); // creates an instance of second - X = 100, Y = 100
    t=new third(); // creates an instance of third, which creates a different instance of 
                   // second and updates X and Y to 200
    sec.update(); // prints the original instance of second - X and Y still contain 100
}
```

You can see in your output - `First Second Second Third 100 100` - that the `second` constructor is called twice, which means two instances of the `second` class are created. Only in one of them you set the values of X and Y to 200.

Answer (score 1):

Understand this :

```
public first(){
    sec=new second();
    t=new third();
    sec.update();
}
```

First when you instantiate `second` class the **x and y holds 100 each**

Then you instantiate `third` class and in `third class's constructor` you create a **different instance of second with different value of x and y**

Finally calling `update()` with the **first created instance of second** so it will print

`x =100 and y= 100`

If you call the `update()`with the **second created instance of second class** then it will print

`x =200 and y=200`

Answer (score 0):

Both are different instances:

```
sec=new second(); // OBJECT 1
t=new third();  // OBJECT 2  holds x=200 ,y=200 
sec.update(); // OBJECT 1
```

Here, `sec` is pointing to an object with `x` and `y` values as 100. (OBJECT 1)

`t=new third();` is another object and you created another second object (OBJECT 2 with values 200 for `x` and `y`) and changed values to 200 there (it is a different object in memory).

But in the last line, you are printing OBJECT 1 (sec) you created, so you are getting 100 s for `x` and `y`.  Understand that both are different instances.

`sec` points to the second object in memory which holds 100 for `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly there are two time of class second object have been created; because whenever we call the new ClassName() then only single object created but you did

```
public class third {
    second sec;

    public third() {
        sec = new second();
        sec.setX(200);
        sec.setY(200);
        System.out.println("Third");
    }
}
```

&

```
public class first {
    second sec;
    third t;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("First");
        new first();

    }

    public first() {
        sec = new second();
        t = new third();
        sec.update();
    }

}
```

In your code you created two objects not single and every have their own instance setter/getter method.

Hope you clear now.